# Minimize memory usage with a multi-frame MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have a MovieClip in Flash with 100 frames. Each frame contains a certain icon I need to use in a project. I create instances of this icon MovieClip wherever I need an icon to appear, and `gotoAndStop` to a certain frame to display that icon.

Will storing a 100 icons in a single movieclip cause every single icon to be created in memory whenever I create an instance of the MovieClip? If I stored each icon in the library and attached only the icon that is needed, would that consume less memory than creating this MovieClip that has all the icons in it?

Comment: If you want all icons in one place then create one single image and use `SpriteSheet` technique to display particular icon. This is actually used in games ( designing levels ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each icon that goes into the 100 frames MovieClip is an image you can easily enough export that image for actionscript and access only the image you need.

Another idea is to create a static class that stores each icon frame as a symbol in a static array(if you want to access the icon by index) or Dictionary(if you want to retrieve it by name).

e.g.

```
package{

    import flash.display.Bitmap;

    public class Icons{

        public static const assets:Vector.<Bitmap> = Vector.<Bitmap>([new Icon01ASExportName(),//instance bitmaps once
                                                                      new Icon02ASExportName(),//reuse them later multiple times
                                                                      ...
                                                                      new Icon99ASExportName()]);
    }

}
```

Yet another is to generate a SpriteSheet, either once and save it as a file, either at runtime, then [copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) to paste the icon from the right rectangle of the main spritesheet. You've got multiple tools available for generating the spritesheet:

- [Zoë](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2011/02/zoe-export-swf-animation-as-easeljs-spritesheets.html)
- [SWFSheet](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2939)
- [Flash CS6](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-web/generating-sprite-sheets-using-flash-professional-cs6/)
- [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) (if you have movieclips, you can export them as an image sequence to drop into the software)

There are also ways to [generate a spritesheet at runtime](https://github.com/emibap/Dynamic-Texture-Atlas-Generator).

For some nicely explained video tutorials on spritesheets and BitmapData by Lee Brimelow:  Sprite Sheets and Blitting - Part [1](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=140),[2](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=141) and [3](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=142).

Comment: SpriteSheets sound cool but considering I want scalable vector display, I'll have to rerender all fixed size icons whenever the stage size or window is scaled for instance. And during animation would SpriteSheets be faster than the vector versions? Even a little tradeof making the icons look blurry because its bitmaps is fine as long as I can animate it and do basic things. Or render 2x the size icons into the SpriteSheet so it looks fine during animating. Any known techniques in this direction? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: When you go to a frame with an icon on it, Flash will create a new instance of that icon. When you leave that frame, Flash will make that icon eligible for garbage collection, unless you force it to hold the instance in memory somehow, such as using addEvenListener where the method that is the listener is the icon or somewhere inside it.

I think the memory usage is likely to be higher for the goToAndStop vs. the new instance. If you are not experiencing problems with goToAndStop(), you are unlikely to experience additional issues by instantiating a new icon each time you switch from one icon to another. The other people who have answered are quite right that you will use fewer CPU cycles by instantiating all the icons only once (by whatever method), and then simply using the same one every time you use that icon. However, your overall memory footprint will be higher, because you will have all of the icons (even ones you are not currently using) in memory all the time.

If you want to go the route of only instantiating each on once, I'd suggest you go with Lazy Loading, where you only instantiate each icon when it is first used. One way to do this is to use what you already have and visit the frame the *first* time you want to use a specific icon, then store the BitmapData or a reference to the icon itself after that and reuse it. Another way is to [build a swc](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-guide-to-creating-and-using-swcs/?search_index=4) and use a similar pattern.

None of this requires a static variable BTW, since it sounds like you're not using tons of different copies of your icon MC. Even if you are, it's probably better to handle referencing the icons you have through [dependency injection](http://www.developria.com/2009/09/as3-dependency-injection-demys.html).

I think you are probably asking about file size, however, vs. actual memory usage. The answer to *that* questions is that all assets that are used by your fla get compiled into the swf, regardless of whether they are in a MovieClip, a SWC, or in the library with Export for Actionscript in Frame N checked.

**I get it, I've got boobs, I'm guessing**
Try this, to verify my "guess."

1. Create a swf that has a keyframe on frame 1.
2. Draw a circle there.
3. Put another keyframe on frame 10. Draw a square.
4. In Publish Settings, check "Generate size report."

Now, you know (or you should know) that this swf can display the circle on frame 1, even if the assets compiled on frame 10 have not yet been downloaded. So, is there *any possible way* that the square could be loaded into memory before Frame 10 has been downloaded? Hint: the answer is no.

Now ask yourself this: Do you think Macromedia wrote a special version of MC that is *incapable* of lazy loading that the MC that is the main Document Class that Flash generated for the movie you made above so obviously handles so well?

The Macromedia engineers did a lot of things that in hindsight look pretty stupid, but they're not *that* incompetent.

Comment: No I'm not asking about file size. I understand perfectly what's going on during the compile/build/debug cycle, I just wanted to know if individual icon clips would be faster (creation) or lighter (memory) than a big MC with a 100 icons in it. Actually someone (or I) should just do a speedtest and memtest to verify everything. Otherwise both George and you are operating on educated guesswork which is not reliable.

Comment: I've spent spent quite a lot of time with [the literature](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2010/02/10/optimise-as3-for-speed/) and the profiler, so my educated guesses are pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

If your icons are Bitmaps then each movieclip will share the same data - the only memory increase will be due to more movieclips, rather than their contents (which shouldnt be a problem).

If your icons are not Bitmaps (other movieclips, shapes, buttons etc), then everything gets duplicated, so memory usage will increase a lot faster as more movieclips are added.

Another consideration is that lots of movieclips on screen will have more of an effect on FPS than simpler objects so you may want to consider adding the icon itself rather than the movieclip even if you are using Bitmaps.

Comment: Are you sure everything gets duplicated if they are shapes? Per instance? Have you actually tested/seen memory usage or you are just assuming? I'll accept your answer if you have some more scientific data or refs that say so. I'm a sucker for premature optimization, so I'll go ahead and split each icon into a seperate MC, only to figure that it doesn't help at all! So just trying to prevent that situation!

Comment: @Geotarget Lee is right: think about it. If you have 100 frames in one MovieClip Flash will allocate a certain amount of resources for it (i.e. all of it's frames) so for each icon you use, basically you use the resources of 100 since each holds a 100 elements on frames. Also MovieClip in general is slightly greedier since it's a dynamic class as opposed to Sprite for example. Now it might be that your icons are simple vector icons, in which case they could be individual MovieClip instances used once when needed. If they are complex(multiple paths with many points and multiple transparent ...

Comment: @Geotarget ...gradients) using a spritesheet means releasing some of the strain on the cpu to handle the vector graphics in exchange for a wee bit of memory to store the pixels version

Comment: @George I think that's not correct. Flash doesn't create the assets in each of those frames until they are actually on stage, and it makes them available for garbage collection once they are removed. The definition that allows Flash to be able to create the instance when it calls new instance() will either be exported right before the frame where the MC is or on the Export for AS frame, depending on whether you tick the box. It will know about the 100 frames, to populate the totalFrames variable, but it doesn't instantiate them from the beginning.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I didn't know that. I though all the content of the frames is loaded into memory when a movie clip in instantiated.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza - Anyways Amy is just guessing so I suppose its as good as yours. Someone should do a speedtest and memtest to actually verify each method.

Comment: I did a quick test to confirm what i stated in my answer (as i dont use the timeline anymore so possible my info is out of date) - but results were inconclusive. I'll do a more involved test if i get a chance at some pont

Comment: @Geotarget: I actually wasn't guessing on that one. I build enterprise-level projects using the timeline, so my understanding of how it works is pretty firm. BTW, it's really rude to ask people for help and when someone comes along who actually knows what they're talking about to declare that you think they are guessing. You should consider what you hope to gain by doing that and why you feel it's ok.